# Using & in textblock text WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, textbox

When I was adding a hardcoded text in WPF textbox I found a diificulty in adding "&" symbol. I wonder why it is like that . Anybody having a reason and solution?

```
<TextBlock  Text="Shipping & handling"></TextBlock>
```

my error was like
Error:  Expected the following token: ";".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XAML is valid XML and you can't use an & in XML without escaping it 
Use & amp;(remove space) instead of &.

From Wikipedia:

> Unlike traditional HTML with its large range of character entity
>   references, in XML there are only five predefined character entity
>   references. These are used to escape characters that are markup
>   sensitive in certain contexts(remove space & use): 
>  •& amp; → & (ampersand, U+0026)
>  •& lt; →
>   < (less-than sign, U+003C)
>  •& gt;→ > (greater-than sign, U+003E)
>   
> •& quot; → " (quotation mark, U+0022) 
> •& apos; → ' (apostrophe, U+0027)

Comment: you can include the Wikipedia link also for more reference

Answer (score 7):

use `&amp;` instead of `&`  hence your code will be like the following:

```
  <TextBlock  Text="Shipping &amp;  handling"></TextBlock>
```

[As per MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx)

> XAML uses character entities defined in XML for special characters.
> This topic describes some specific character entities and general
> considerations for other XML concepts in XAML. Most character entities
> and escape sequences that are typically used to write XAML markup are
> defined by XML. This topic does not provide the complete list of these
> entities; a detailed reference for the entities can be found in
> external documentation, such as in XML specifications. However, for
> convenience, this topic lists some of the specific XML character
> entities that are typically used in XAML markup.
> Following are some of them:
> [image]